# R2DBC pool closes all connections before each query

Tags: java, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

We're using the latest versions of `spring-data-r2dbc`, `r2dbc-pool` and `r2dbc-postgresql` for connecting to a PostgreSQL database using a connection pool. We noticed some high response times, much higher than the query response times taken from the database itself (`query_store.qs_view`)

We added a `metricsRecorder` to the pool and, for debugging purposes, we're only printing when each method is invoked. It seems that before each SQL query, we get as many `recordDestroyLatency` invocations as there are connections in the pool and the same number of `recordAllocationSuccessAndLatency` invocations. We assumed that this means that each connection gets closed and reopened before each query. We then compared with the database logs and it proves this is true: there is the same number of `could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` followed by `connection received:` messages.

Why would this happen? Below is the code we're using for creating the connection factory.

```
@Configuration
open class DatabaseConfiguration : AbstractR2dbcConfiguration() {

//some variable initialisations

    @Bean
    override fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
        val cf = PostgresqlConnectionFactory(
            PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host(hostname)
                .database(dbName)
                .schema(dbSchema)
                .username(dbUsername)
                .password(dbPassword)
                .build()
        )
        val cp = ConnectionPoolConfiguration.builder(cf)
            .initialSize(poolInitialSize)
            .maxSize(poolMaxSize)
            .metricsRecorder(DatabaseMetricsRecorder())
            .build()
        return ConnectionPool(cp)
    }
}
```

As mentioned, the `DatabaseMetricsRecorder` just prints each operation. For the query itself, we're extending the `ReactiveCrudRepository` interface. The `ConnectionPoolConfiguration` is in its simplest form here, we tried adding parameters like `maxIdleTime` or `validationQuery` (as we'll have for production) but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug in R2DBC pool, here's the [issue](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-pool/issues/129). As a workaround, `maxLifeTime` should be explicitly set, for example I set it to the maximum allowed value in milliseconds (otherwise, if set to a value greater than the maximum allowed value in milliseconds, R2DBC will throw an Exception):

```
    val cp = ConnectionPoolConfiguration.builder(cf)
        .initialSize(poolInitialSize)
        .maxSize(poolMaxSize)
        .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofMillis(Long.MAX_VALUE))
        .metricsRecorder(DatabaseMetricsRecorder())
        .build()
```